# Trigger for input is not invoking in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small snippet that changes the textbox size based on its input

I want to use jquery for all functions as much as possible but when I try with

```
.trigger("input")
```

Its not invoking.

```html
<html><head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #myInput {
  font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal Roboto, sans-serif;
  min-width: 40px;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <input value="" id="myInput" style="width: 10px;">
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTextWidth(el) {
  var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var font = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font');
  var text = el.value;

  context.font = font;
  var textMeasurement = context.measureText(text);

  return Math.min(350,textMeasurement.width);
}

var input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var width = Math.floor(getTextWidth(e.target));
    console.log(width)

var widthInPx = (width + 10) + "px";
  e.target.style.width = widthInPx;
}, false);


$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('myInput').value = "Johnny Bravo"
//document.getElementById('myInput').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
$("#myInput").val("Hello World").trigger("input")

});

</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Because you have added the `input` listener with the native `addEventListener` but are triggering the event with jQuery's `trigger`. I guess your question is how do I add an `input` event listener using jQuery's `on`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you were listening for the native `input` event instead of jQuery's event system, so when you used `trigger` to dispatch the event, there was a disconnect and your listener wasn't firing. Basically you shouldn't mix the event systems, native and jQuery.

I made the `input` handler reusable by defining a function `handleInput` which is now added to your input like `.on('input', handleInput)`.

```html
<html><head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #myInput {
  font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal Roboto, sans-serif;
  min-width: 40px;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <input value="" id="myInput" style="width: 10px;">
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTextWidth(el) {
  var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var font = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font');
  var text = el.value;

  context.font = font;
  var textMeasurement = context.measureText(text);

  return Math.min(350,textMeasurement.width);
}

var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
function handleInput(e) {
  console.log('input')
  var width = Math.floor(getTextWidth(e.target));
    console.log(width)

var widthInPx = (width + 10) + "px";
  e.target.style.width = widthInPx;
}
input.addEventListener('input', handleInput, false);


$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('myInput').value = "Johnny Bravo"
//document.getElementById('myInput').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

$('#myInput').val('Hello World').on('input', handleInput).trigger('input')


});

</script>


</body></html>
```